# CNOT gate path interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

I have a question on paper "https://doi.org/10.1038/nature02054".
In this paper, the CNOT gate is realized using a beam displacer for higher stability. The figure below shows a 1:1 mapping from (a) to (b). In (a), the interference where C1 meets with T0 is needed for a CNOT gate. This interference happens when the two photons meet at "1/3" BS. However, in (b), the interference occurs from the indistinguishability between {(C1$\rightarrow T_{out}$ mode) + (T+$\rightarrow C_{out}$)} and {(C1$\rightarrow C_{out}$ mode) + (T+$\rightarrow T_{out}$)}. This is a problem because both cases have a different time delay due to the beam displacer [see drawing below]. Therefore interference cannot happen, and thus, the CNOT gate fails.

Can someone help me understand where I'm wrong?

[image: paper fig]

[image: The delay from beam displacer]

Comment: Try also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How big is the delay, compared to the spatial extent of the photons? (And could it be a cartoon picture, and the actual setup is designed such as to minimize this delay?)

Comment: P.S.: Try to link to an openly accessible version of the paper (arxiv!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are assuming the two photons arrive at the first beam-displacer with zero relative delay, but their relative delay at the input is in fact a free parameter in the experiment. If the induced delay between the two paths through a beam-displacer is $\tau$, then it's easy to verify that by delaying the control-qubit photon by $\tau$ at the input, the relative delay between the photons is zero in both output ports, and they therefore interfere.

For example: $T_{in} \to C_{out}$ receives a delay of $2\tau$, while $C_{in} \to C_{out}$ is delayed by $\tau$, to which you then add the delay at the input.